# Repeated incrementation of a floating point number

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm looking at some legacy code that defines some grid points along the axis `f`.

```
int main(){
    double f[9];
    int i = 0;
    for (double a = 0; a <= 1; a += 0.125){
        f[i++] = a;
    }
}
```

I'm worried about the repeated addition of 1 / 8 to `a`, and the loop not running correctly. This is because I don't think you can add floating point values like this and rely on it being exactly 1 when `i` is 8.

Or is this code OK and I should stop worrying? (The code is at least 20 years old apparently and has never caused trouble - although in the original version, `double a` was declared outside the loop, I'm reading up on why that is.).

Comment: Yeah, that is terrible,

Comment: You should **always** iterate using the array bounds - everything else is asking for trouble

Comment: What the others have said is 100% correct.  That said, it's worth pointing out that 0.125 is an exact power of two, so this code will work fine on any non-esoteric platform.

Comment: No, this code is not OK because it is *non-obvious*.

Comment: "in the original version, double a was declared outside the loop, I'm reading up on why that is." If I remember correctly, before C99 you had to do it that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is fine when compiled with a C compiler that provides either exactly IEEE 754 semantics or a close approximation of them (say, FLT_EVAL_METHOD>0, or even arbitrary excess precision for sub-expressions and arbitrary roundings to the nominal precision).

The problems you fear are:

1. representation error, where `0.125` is not exactly 1/8, and
2. operation error, where `+` is not exactly mathematical addition. None of these happen for this particular program.

0.125 requires 1 bit of precision to be represented exactly in base 2. This means that the floating-point number used by the program in these conditions is exactly the intended 1/8. Furthermore, it can be added to itself 2<sup>53</sup> times before there is any approximation in the addition.

---

This reasoning is not correct for other increment steps. For instance, the variation of your program below leaves one index of the array, `f[100]`, uninitialized with at least my compiler (which implements strict IEEE 754 semantics):

```
int main(){
    double f[101];
    int i = 0;
    for (double a = 0; a <= 1; a += 0.01){
        printf("%.16e %d\n", a, i);
        f[i++] = a;
    }
}
```

When I run it I get at the last lines:

```
...
9.8000000000000065e-01 98
9.9000000000000066e-01 99
```

`f[100]` is never written to because of both representation error and operation error that occur when trying to add `0.01` repeatedly to itself in binary floating-point.

Comment: That's very reassuring. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: @PaulLogue But [UnholySheep comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394881/repeated-incrementation-of-a-floating-point-number#comment75789459_44394881) is very important.

Comment: Although your answer is perfectly correct, I'd have liked to seen some mentioning that it is definitely not *good code*. On a (maybe theoretical) machine that would use BCD aritmethics and representation, it would most probably not work, with an increment of, for example 1/10 instead of 1/8, it wouldn't work as well. Programming a loop that works properly with **one** increment and not anoher is not good practice.

Comment: @tofro I avoid discussions of style on StackOverflow, but it is a fact that changing only a couple of constants in the program, seemingly innocently, make it cease to work as intended. I have added an example. The other kind of bug that seems possible, an out of bounds write to `f`, requires a loop with many more iterations (the accumulated error has to become comparable to the increment).

Comment: @PascalCuoq Coding style and semantic are two different things. Here, the code is wrong by nature.

Comment: @Stargateur It's only wrong if you do not understand how floating-point works. You could as well say that `for (int i=0; i!=200; i+=2) …` is wrong and should use `<=`. It's not wrong. It works. If you understand even and odd integers, you see that it needn't be changed. If you understand floating-point, you see that the original program needn't be changed (the question says “legacy”. Changing legacy code gratuitously introduces bugs where there were none, too)

Comment: @PascalCuoq "The code is fine when compiled with a C compiler that provides either exactly IEEE 754", so this code is implemented behavior. I just want to say that this should not be considered as "The code is fine". Changing legacy can reveal problem in legacy code too. Whatever I made my answer so I have nothing to add.

Comment: @Stargateur Note that you cut the sentence from my answer short. Also note that the declaration `int x = 40000;` has implementation-defined behavior. While it is not impossible to write code that behaves identically on any standard-compliant compiler, such an exercise would be akin to writing in an esoteric language. In practice, no nontrivial piece of C code does not rely on implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score -2):

C standard leaves floating number **implemented behavior**, a lot of compiler use IEEE 754 standard. Your code is not Ok because:

1. Your code **must** be compile with IEEE 754 standard or similar standard with the same behavior.
2. It's hard to read. When you read the code the exact behavior is not obvious.
3. This is not the right way to iterate over array in C.

Imagine, someone doesn't know that requirement, and don't compile with IEEE 754 standard. The behavior could be something completely different. For example, your code could produce a out of bounds, and this is undefined behavior, your program could crash.

---

That said, an example of code that have the same behavior of your code when compiled with IEEE 754 standard:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void) {
  double f[9];
  size_t const size_f = sizeof f / sizeof *f;

  double a = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size_f; i++) {
    f[i] = a;
    a += 0.125;
  }
}
```

Comment: So all downvotes, are people who loop on `double` to fill an array ? I can live with that.